# Why did animals evolve genders?

Tags: evolution, sex

The majority of animals have two genders, and both are needed in reproduction. It seems like it would be more advantageous for creatures to be hermaphrodites, since they could mate with any member of their species instead of needing to find a partner of the opposite gender. Why did animals evolve to have genders instead of being hermaphrodites?

Comment: The title is a bit misleading. Hermaphrodites still have genders, if you consider the reproduction system. The title looks more like that you ask for a reason for meiotic reproduction, as opposed to mitosis, which is an interesting question, too.

Comment: Even yeast have a gender or mating type, called as A type or α type